# Run Task independently?

Tags: c#, task, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using the new Hosted Service in Net Core 2.1 to recieve some messages  via RabbitMq.

While I can get a fair number of requests, I do not expect dozens or so at the same time. But processing a task can take a lot of time (hours...days)

I do not want to wait for my RabbitMq message to stay around that long - if I retrieved the message, I can ack the message.

Is just starting a new Thread via Task.Run() a good idea in that scenario?

I thought about quueing the message in an internal Queue, but found no good solution on Linux Net core.

Current Code looks like this:

```
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Starting 
     nameof(NewTaskHandlerService)}");
          await _rabbit.SubscribeAsync<CalculationTask>(async (message) =>
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"New Task: {message.InstanceId}");
                        try
                        {
// this can take ages, I want to start this independently
                            Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                                {
                                    var scopedProcessingService =
                                        scope.ServiceProvider
                                            .GetRequiredService<ICalculationTaskHandler>();

                                    await scopedProcessingService.StartCalculationTask(message);

                                }
                            });

                            return new Ack();

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(0, e, "Error while handling new task. Marking Workflow {} task {} as failed",
                                message.ParentCalculationId, message.InstanceId);
                            return new Nack(true);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use Hangfire. It is designed for long running operations. See https://www.hangfire.io

Comment: By "internal queue", do you mean an in-memory queue? You could then use a BlockingCollection: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-2.1

Answer (score 2):

Starting a new `Task` every time you receive a message has disadvantages

1. It's unreliable, if you get too many messages, that much `Task`s will overflow the memory and app will simply crash.
2. No real-time view of messages state, how much of them are currently processing, failed, succeeded.
3. No ability to retry process failed messages.
4. Messages are processed instantly, no way to process it after some period of time (ex. process nightly)

Use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) which will handle processing messages in background gradually (with other benefits, like retry, etc.)

Comment: Thank you - when I last researched this topic (net core preview days) both libs where in development for Net Core and Hangfire had an ugly license.